# Dynamic parameterized and parameterless Action execution

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, parameters, action

Below I have a few methods that help me execute parametered and parameterless actions, and it works. 
However I have a problem that I want to get rid off, the problem is that when i call

```
Execute<Action<Myclass>, Myclass>(ActionWithParameter);
```

I am passing the `MyClass` 2 times. The first time to define the parameter required by my Action `ActionWithParameter` and the 2nd time to define the type of parameter i am expecting in my `Execute<TAction, TType>` method.

So my question is: is there a way to get rid of the 2nd Generic `TType` and somehow get it from the first generic `TAction` ?

Maybe something like `TAction<TType>`?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Execute<Action>(ActionWithoutParameter);
            Execute<Action<Myclass>, Myclass>(ActionWithParameter);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ActionWithoutParameter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("executed no parameter");
        }

        private static void ActionWithParameter(Myclass number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("executed no parameter   " + number.ID);
        }

        private static void Execute<TAction>(TAction OnSuccess)
        {
            Execute<TAction, Myclass>(OnSuccess);
        }
        private static void Execute<TAction, TType>(TAction OnSuccess)
        {
            if (OnSuccess is Action)
            {
                Action method = OnSuccess as Action;
                method();
            }
            else if (OnSuccess is Action<TType>)
            {
                Myclass myclass = new Myclass() { ID = 123 };
                TType result = (TType)(object)myclass;
                Action<TType> method = OnSuccess as Action<TType>;
                method(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I recommend choosing a tag to replace with the language tag, so this gets more attention.

Comment: I added c# as tag now. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a non-generic and generic version of the method will do the trick:

```
    public static void Execute<TType>(Action<TType> OnSuccess) 
         where TType : Myclass // gets rid of unnecessary type-casts - or you just use Action<Myclass> directly - without the generic parameter...
    { 
         // throw an exception or just do nothing - it's up to you...
         if (OnSuccess == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException("OnSuccess"); // return;

         TType result = new Myclass() { ID = 123 };
         OnSuccess(result);
    }

    public static void Execute(Action OnSuccess) 
    { 
        if (OnSuccess == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(); // return;

        OnSuccess();            
    }
```

(However I'm not so sure about the purpose of the result generation + action execution - simply using only the non-generic `Execute(Action)` version could probably do the trick as well...)